# error when i'm trying to set text in qTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qtwidgets, qtextcursor

I'm using Qt 5.3 with MSVC2013. Here is some part of my code:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
    connect(okButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(onOKClicked()));
}

void MainWindow::onOKClicked(){
    arr0.Put(addBox->value(),posBox->value());
    QString str = arr0.GetArrText();
    arrayContent->setText(str);
}
```

The content of the variable "str" is alright as it is working with qDebug.

The arrayContent variable is a QTextEdit. When I try to use setText(), I'm getting the following error:

```
QTextCursor::setPosition: Position '7' out of range
```

Do you know why it is happening to me?

Comment: Are you affected by [this bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-38178)?

Comment: maybe this. But what must I do to avoid this problem? Only downgrade my Qt version? Is there a some workaround?

Answer (score 2):

For some mysterious reason cursor position is not updated correctly when you set new content and old cursor points to beyond new content. This is defiantly a bug in Qt.

As a workaround you can try this:

```
void MainWindow::onOKClicked(){
    arr0.Put(addBox->value(),posBox->value());
    QString str = arr0.GetArrText();
    arrayContent->moveCursor(QTextCursor::Start);
    arrayContent->setText(str);
    arrayContent->selectAll(); // or arrayContent->moveCursor(QTextCursor::End);
}
```

---

Or you can try operate directly on document:

```
void MainWindow::onOKClicked(){
    arr0.Put(addBox->value(),posBox->value());
    QString str = arr0.GetArrText();
    arrayContent->moveCursor(QTextCursor::Start);
    arrayContent->document()->setPlainText(str);
    arrayContent->selectAll(); // or arrayContent->moveCursor(QTextCursor::End);
}
```

Comment: But I didn't add some content in this textedit area before running setText(). And your code generates the same mistake.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is generated when new content is bigger the old one (at begging you have zero length text). If workaround doesn't silence it then you have no choice to ignore this (or try find other workaround, I have another proposal). If this error appears only in logs it doesn't have impact on end user so you can ignore that.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The problem is that my program is crashes after this message. But I already think that problem in methods called by object "arr0", maybe some errors when I allocate memory in this methods. But why in this case program execution reaches call of setPlainText()?